# dimple.js Cannot Fix these issues

Tags: d3.js, charts, dimple.js

I have some needs in dimple js and i cannot find anything related to my query anywhere. I made a simple bar chart but the values are arranged in ascending order and Y Axis Labels are hiding and the values are converted as 1k,2k.

Please help me to fix these 3 issues:

1. To Stop sorting the data in ascending order
2. To Shorten the labels in Y axis
3. To Show the exact value as in json and not convert it to 1k,2k

   ```
    var data = [
                   {
                       "Service" : "Primary Services" ,
                       "Total Services" : "10065"
                   } ,
                   {
                       "Service" : "PCP" ,
                       "Total Services" : "851"
                   } ,
                   {
                       "Service" : "scientist" ,
                       "Total Services" : "8818"

               } ,
               {
                   "Service" : "NP/PA/CNS" ,
                   "Total Services" : "5854"
               } ,
               {
                   "Service" : "FQHC/RHC" ,
                   "Total Services" : "8574"

               }

           ];


   var svg = dimple.newSvg("#types-of-services", 500, 300);

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);



   // Set bounds
   myChart.setBounds(0, 0, "5%", "5%")

   myChart.setMargins("75px", "0px", "20px", "50px");

   var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Total Services");

   var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Service");

    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);


   x.fontSize = "12";
   y.fontSize = "12";

   x.fontFamily = "Roboto";
   y.fontFamily = "Roboto";

   myChart.draw(1700);

   x.titleShape.remove();

   $(window).on('resize', resize);
   $('.sidebar-control').on('click', resize);

   function resize() {


       myChart.draw(0, true);


       x.titleShape.remove();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure Axis will Sort, Display as 1K, 2K etc., Use category axis instead...

```
// var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Total Services");
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Total Services");
```